# Apache Camel: RouteBuilder with CxfEndpoint

Tags: java, spring, cxf, apache-camel

### Hello!

I'm trying to implement a Camel route with Java DSL and RouteBuilder. I want to send from a timer endpoint to a cxf endpoint.

### Code:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        
        CamelContext camelContext = getContext();
    
        CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
        cxfEndpoint.setAddress("http://localhost:8088/interface");
        cxfEndpoint.setWsdlURL("wsdl/contract.wsdl");
        cxfEndpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);
        cxfEndpoint.setDataFormat(DataFormat.PAYLOAD);

        try {
            camelContext.addEndpoint("myEndpoint", cxfEndpoint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=500")
                .transform(constant("DummyBody"))
                .to("cxf://myEndpoint");        
    }

}
```

This route gets inserted into a camel context defined using Spring XML (where I have some other routes).

### Problem:

I'm getting the following error:

```
karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-78" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer fo
r endpoint: Endpoint[cxf://myEndpoint]. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serviceClass must be specified
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:395)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:114)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.startProducer(ProducerCache.java:145)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:175)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
        ....
```

Now the error is pretty straight forward, but [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) says:

> This option is only required by POJO mode. If the wsdlURL option is
> provided, serviceClass is not required for PAYLOAD and MESSAGE mode.

### Questions:

If I'm using PAYLOAD mode, why I still need a service class? Am I missing something when creating the cxf endpoint?

### Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already setup a CxfEndpoint to use, so your route should be just like this

```
from("timer://my-timer?fixedRate=true&period=500")
                .transform(constant("DummyBody"))
                .to(myEndpoint);
```