# Apache Camel - CXF: general endpoint's customer configuration

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, integration

I have many WSDL(>100) files in my projects (many WS java interfaces generated). I want to use general configuration for cxf endpoints, not to configure many endpoints in camel xml configuration file for each ws.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="orderEndpoint"
    address="http://localhost:9000/order/"
    serviceClass="camelinaction.order.OrderEndpoint"/>
```

Is it any other way to configure camel cxf endpoint without manually adding it to xml file for each ws?
Is it possible to use some camel annotations in generated interfaces (automatically)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Camel annotation to auto-discover JAX-WS interfaces in the classpath and load them as CXF endpoints. That's something too specific to your usecase.

What you can do is use programmatic Spring configuration to register the endpoints in the Spring registry which Camel then uses to resolve endpoints.

Create a class and annotate it with [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) and make it implement [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) in order to get a callback along with a `BeanDefinitionRegistry` which will allow you to add new beans to the registry. Find an example here: [Spring - Programmatically generate a set of beans (answer 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374000/spring-programmatically-generate-a-set-of-beans/28550486#28550486).

So now that you have the means to register new beans, you'll need to find the JAX-WS endpoints by searching your classpath. This SO question lists several alternatives: [Find Java classes implementing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435890/find-java-classes-implementing-an-interface). Since you're using Spring, I would suggest you try out [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166959/1970990).

You'll need to define a technique to generate the bean name and the URL in a meaningful and predictable way, so you can access the bean from the Camel route, and the endpoint from the outside.

Don't forget enabling `<context:component-scan />` in your Spring XML to instruct Spring to search Java classes for components.

P.S.: This does not require you to use the Java DSL of Camel. You're simply using Java code to introspect the classpath and dynamically inject the appropriate beans into the Spring registry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java DSL (rather than Spring XML) to declare your endpoints programmatically. See the question [Apache Camel: RouteBuilder with CxfEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478905/apache-camel-routebuilder-with-cxfendpoint) for an example.

Dynamically discovering all of your web services is a separate issue, with many different possible solutions (such as naming conventions, implementing a shared interface, annotation processing).

Comment: I know I can rewrite it in Java DSL but it would be the same. The problem is with generating cxf-endpoints automatically, because I have already defined many WSDL and ws interfaces in my project. I'm interested in just the ability to dynamically discovering all web services as camel cxf-endpoints. I don't know how I can implement it, using annotations for example?

Comment: Maybe it's posiible to add my implemented web services to camel context as cxfEndpoint in some automatic way?

Comment: If you want to use annotations then have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime. Your question isn't really about CXF or Camel IMHO - you are just looking for a way to discover classes with certain features.